# Set UINavigationBar height proportionally to screen size

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uikit

I have 5 tabs in UITabBarController and each of them is embedded in a UINavigationController. I would like to set the height of this tab to 8% of the screen, but I cannot set constraints to StoryBoard, also if I try to set it from code it turns black and break UI controls.
The code for my UINavigationController is this:

```
class NavBarController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image"))
        self.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        var bounds = self.navigationBar.bounds
        bounds.size.height += self.view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
        bounds.origin.y -= self.view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.black, UIColor.white]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image(fromLayer: gradient), for: .default)
    }
    
    func image(fromLayer layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return outputImage!
    }
}
```

I tried by setting:

```
self.navigationBar.frame.size.height = (self.view.superview?.frame.height)! * 0.08
self.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

at the beginning of viewDidLayoutSubviews, but it does not work and also breaks the gradient background. Can someone help me? The ideal solution would be through storyboard, but I cannot simply set the UINavigationItem height constraint to its view height.

Comment: Have you tried executing this code by overriding `layout()` or `updateConstraints()`? I believe `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is too late in the render loop. You'll want to subclass `UINavigationBar` and do the overrides in your custom subclass.

Comment: @user1922718 no, I haven't tried it because I had some problems regarding the gradient, but I will try it. Thank you. How do I access the superview height? self.navigationController.view.superview...?

Comment: Calling `superview` on any view will give you its parent view, so long as the view is in a view hierarchy.  So you could get the superview's height by calling `view.superview.frame.height`

Comment: @user1922718 I tried in different ways, by overriding layoutSubviews(), updateConstraints() and so on, also I tried again in the controller. Nothing, I cannot set this f*cking bar height.

Comment: One other thing you can try is subclass `UINavigationBar` and write a `didSet` observer for the `frame` variable. Then set a breakpoint in the debugger and take note every time this variable is changed and at what point in the render loop. This will give you clues as to when you need to set the bar height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time looking into this, I found that UINavigationBar is given a height of 44pts several times throughout the transition process. Since UIKit is insisting on a height of 44, I decided to employ some trickery with a custom setter.

```
class NavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    private var _frame: CGRect!
    override var frame: CGRect {
        set {
            _frame = CGRect(origin: newValue.origin, size: CGSize(width: newValue.width, height: 22))
        }
        get {
            _frame
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm forcing the height of the navigation bar to 22 pts. However, after compiling and running the nav bar is still 44. Why? Because UIKit is also setting a constraint, forcing the height to 44. This means that AutoLayout is reverting the height to 44 upon layout. Seems that this is something Apple really doesn't want you to change.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, some minutes ago I read the same in the documentation, I guess I will create my own NavBar then, because I have to follow a mockup. Thank you for your time